# Is a given vector contained in an irreducible subspace of a representation?

Tags: group-theory, representation-theory

Let $G$ be a finite group and $\pi: G \to \operatorname{End}(V)$ a complex non-trivial representation on the vector space $V$.

Given a vector $v\in V$, does there exist an irreducible subspace $W\subseteq V$ with $v\in W$?

I am guessing the answer is no. My intuition tells me to look for (say) a two-dimensional representation of a group on $\mathbb{C}^2$ with only two invariant one-dimensional subspaces $\mathbb{C}^2= V_1\oplus V_2$ and then we can carefully create the vector $v$ so that it does not live in $V_1$ and $V_2$. But I don't know many examples of representations.

Any help is highly appreciated!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let's go with your approach.

Suppose $G = \mathbb Z_2 = \{ e, \sigma \} $, where $e$ is the identity element and $\sigma$ is the element of order two. Suppose $V = \mathbb C^2$, and consider the representation $\pi : G \to \text{End}(V)$ defined by
$$ \pi(e) = \begin{bmatrix} 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 1\end{bmatrix}, \qquad \pi(\sigma) = \begin{bmatrix} 1 & 0 \\ 0 & -1\end{bmatrix}.$$
We have the decomposition
$$ V = V_1 \oplus V_2,$$
where $V_1$ and $V_2$ are the one-dimensional irreducible subspaces
$$ V_1 = \{ (x, 0) : x \in \mathbb C \}, \qquad V_2 = \{ (0, y) : y \in \mathbb C \}.$$
(In fact, $V_1$ and $V_2$ are the *only* irreducible subspaces of $V$.)

It's easy to construct a vector $v \in V$ that is neither an element of $V_1$ nor an element of $V_2$. For example, if we take
$$ v = (1, 1),$$
then $v \notin V_1$ and $v \notin V_2$.

Thus we've exhibited a vector $v \in V$ that is not contained in any of the irreducible subspaces of $V$. So in conclusion, the answer to your question is "no", and the gist of the argument is exactly what you outlined in your original post.

Comment: Thanks! To be completely clear: It should be shown that these are the only irreducible subspaces, right? But I think this is obvious here.

Comment: @Andromeda Yes, you do need to show that $V_1$ and $V_2$ are the only irreducible subspaces. And yes, this is true in this example. I've added this point to the body of the answer.

Comment: Thanks for the answer and the beautiful example.

Comment: Wait: why is $\{(x,x): x \in \mathbb{R}\}$ not an irreducible subspace? Isn't every one-dimensional subspace of this representation invariant (and therefore irreducible?)

Comment: I think this is fixed by changing one of the entries in the image of $\sigma$ by $+1$ instead of $-1$.

Comment: @Andromeda Sorry, you're right. I've fixed this.